# Inlining a typescript-defined web worker in an Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, web-worker

In an Angular 16 application bundled with webpack 5, I want to inline a web worker. Ideally with webpack 5, but webpack 4 would also work for now. I instantiate the web worker with a typescript file as follows:

```
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.worker', import.meta.url))
```

Under the hood, webpack transpiles worker.worker.ts to a chunk / js file. Instead of this, I would like to inline the code for this web worker and instantiate it with a blob url. Or in other words: The typescript code should be transpiled and statically included. How can this be achieved? I tried several custom webpack configurations using @angular-builders/custom-webpack without success so far. The only thing that worked to some extend was to use webpack 4's deprecated raw-loader together with ts-loader:

```
import code from '!!raw-loader!ts-loader!./worker.worker.ts';
```

However, as soon as I use an import statement in the worker code with this approach, I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" on the console when running the app. Besides, raw-loader is deprecated now. A similar question is [discussed
here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/14066), but not in the context of Angular.

To get an example running:

```
ng new web-worker-example --skipTests
cd .\web-worker-example\
ng generate web-worker worker
npm install ts-loader raw-loader --save-dev
```

Add greet.ts to import from:

```
export function greet(): string {
  console.log('Hello');
}
```

worker code for the generated worker.worker.ts:

```
//does not work, see console output
import { greet } from './greet';
greet();

//works
console.log('Hi');
```

app.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
//This inlines the worker code with webpack 4 (deprecated). Fails to run when import statements are used in the .ts file.
//@ts-ignore
import code from '!!raw-loader!ts-loader!./worker.worker.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<h1>Angular Web Worker Example</h1>`,
  styles: [],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    //this is what I would like to use:
    const blob = new Blob([code], { type: 'application/javascript' });
    const worker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));

    //current worker instantiation:
    //const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.worker', import.meta.url));
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to inline the web worker code. Maybe there's an issue you're looking to get around by inlining?